# Office 365 REST API

Tags: c#, rest, azure, office365

I am new to office 365 API. My requirement is i need to connect to office365 using REST API.

For authentication purpose i have only

Email

Password

As the fields , Can i generate a session with these? Or I need to collect the Client id , Secret and Return URL in authentication step it self?

I need to build a windows application not a web.

Also after authentication is successful i need to write code for Add Delegate , Update Delegates for Exchange server. Can i connect to these services by using RESt API?

Please help me to do these things.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the user's email/password to retrieve an OAuth token. However you still need to register your application to obtain a client ID. Native applications (like a Windows app) don't use a client secret. Take a look at the [ADAL library for .NET](https://github.com/AzureAD/azure-activedirectory-library-for-dotnet). One of the overloads for `AcquireTokenAsync` take a `UserCredential` object.

The REST APIs do not have any functionality to work with delegates. You can use Exchange Web Services to work with delegates.